# Why method call (i.e. ToString) executed before divisision ( / )?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, formatting, type-conversion

I have a method and want to convert the result to string with a specific format.
Here is my code:

```
private double MinimunWeight()
{
   return 18.5 / Math.Sqrt(Evaluation.Height).ToString("0.0");
}
```

It fails to compile with:

> Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'string'

What's the correct way to achieve that?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to divide a number by a string, which will not work. Are you attempting to return the result of your math as a string?

Comment: Please next time instead of saying "it is impossible"/"it does not work"/"failed" provide exact details - see my edit as an example. Also [avoid thank you notes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean this?

```
private string MinimunWeight()
{
    return (18.5 / Math.Sqrt(Evaluation.Height)).ToString("0.0");
}
```

Comment: Hi Bill, yes. I tried this way but unsuccessful. I got tha same message: Oerator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'string.

Comment: I don't see how that's possible.  Per the MSDN documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sqrt.aspx) Math.Sqrt returns a double, 18.5 is a double.  Double divided by double is ok.  Take that and then ToString it.  You did see that I added a set of Parentheses right?

Comment: Note the parentheses that denote order of operation.

Comment: +1. Consider adding half line on priorities (especially since I've changed title of the post).

Comment: Yes, I did the same. But the error continues. I'll refer to the documentation to see I find something. Thank you Bill!

Comment: Something else must be happening.  You simply can't get that error from that line of code.